# Get the deleted values for a give column in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, variables, triggers, audit

I'm trying to get

```
@OldValue = (select @fieldname from #del)
```

to give me the value. Instead I get the column name for the result. Is there a way to write this so it can output the value. If I write it out like this

```
@OldValue = (select deleted.ID from #del)
```

I get the correct value. Thanks

Comment: Keep in mind that triggers execute **once per batch** not once per row.  if you delete multiple rows at once, this code will fail.

Comment: Thanks,  I do have it in a loop.  The trigger work fine, I just don't know the correct syntax to get the column value back without explicitly writing out the field name

Comment: Inside a trigger the pseudo-table for deleted items is `deleted`.  `select ID from deleted` would return the IDs of each record that was deleted from the table the trigger is associated with.  If you dumped `deleted` to a temp table `#del`, then it's going to depend entirely on how you created your temp table.

Comment: You would do yourself a massive favor by writing set based code in your trigger instead in a loop. Loops of horribly inefficient.